# ActiveMQ Artemis - Get current redelivery count for scheduled messages

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

Using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.20 with these settings on queues:

```xml
<redelivery-delay>600000</redelivery-delay>
<max-delivery-attempts>9</max-delivery-attempts>
```

I'm occasionally seeing build-ups of scheduled messages where it's not always obvious what the reason for the redelivery issue. In order to investigate it would be useful to know how many times message have attempted redelivery since they first were sent. However, I don't see this info recorded in the output of the `listScheduledMessages()` operation. Is it possible to get this detail through any operational API?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the redelivery count of a message by using the management API. You could create a new issue to request an improvement, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS